# customize what to serialize as json in each method of Struts

Tags: java, json, serialization, struts2

I have a Struts 2 application and I'm using JSON to send the information to the Ajax-based client. Now the load model have had several changes and it has become very complex and the application is too slow. So I need to reduce the fields which are serialized in each case. So I have something like this:

Some actions with some methods to retrieve lists of the objects:

```
public class FooAction{
    private List<FooObject> fooObjects;

    public List<FooObject> list1(){ ... };

    public List<FooObject> list2(){ ... };

}
```

For example this object from the model.

```
public class FooObject{
    private String foo1;
    private String foo2;
    private String foo3;
    private String foo4;
}
```

In that model suppose I don't need the 4th property in any call from Ajax so I add the JSON annotation to avoid it to be serialized.

```
public class FooObject{
    private String foo1;
    private String foo2;
    private String foo3;
    private String foo4;

    @JSON(serialize=false)
    public String getFoo4(){...}
}
```

The problem is something like this.

- In the method `list1()` I only need `foo1` and `foo2`, so I'd like to avoid serialization of `foo3` just in this method
- In the method `list2()` I only need `foo1` and `foo3`, so I'd like to avoid serialization of `foo2` just in this method

So the question is if it's an easy way to customize which properties should be serialized in each method. It would be great if I could customize that for example in the xml of struts:

```
<action name="list1" class="fooObject" method="list1">
    <result type="json"/>
</action>

<action name="list2" class="fooObject" method="list2">
    <result type="json"/>
</action>
```

Thanks

Comment: i don't thik this is possible, all you can tell the plugin which all properties you want to exclude when it start serializing the object

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi it would be ok to indicate what to exclude instead of what to include, by I need to customize that for each method not for all methods.

Comment: i understand that but i don't see any such option, r u using struts2-json plugin?

Comment: have you tried `excludeProperties` which can be configured with result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [Customizing Serialization and Deserialization](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) section of the `struts2` documentation. I think that will help you.